# How can I resolve an IndexError in train_y cycle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, index-error

I don't understand where my mistake is:

```
train_dataset = TensorDataset(input_ids, attention_masks, labels)

print('target train 0:', len(np.where(train_y == 0)[0]))
print('target train 1:', len(np.where(train_y == 1)[0]))
print('target train 2:', len(np.where(train_y == 2)[0]))
print('target train 3:', len(np.where(train_y == 3)[0]))
print('target train 4:', len(np.where(train_y == 4)[0]))
print('target train 5:', len(np.where(train_y == 5)[0]))
print('target train 6:', len(np.where(train_y == 6)[0]))

>> target train 0: 6834
target train 1: 1200
target train 2: 0
target train 3: 4397
target train 4: 1112
target train 5: 0
target train 6: 3281

'''How many examples do classes have?'''

class_sample_count = np.array(
    [len(np.where(train_y == t)[0]) for t in np.unique(train_y)])
print("How many examples do classes have?\n", class_sample_count)

# >> [6834 1200 4397 1112 3281]

weight = 1. / class_sample_count

print("weights: ", weight)

# >> weights: [0.00014633 0.00083333 0.00022743 0.00089928 0.00030479]

samples_weight = np.array([weight[t] for t in train_y])

# >> **IndexError: index 6 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5**
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1/ForwardEuler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30059227/indexerror-index-1-is-out-of-bounds-for-axis-0-with-size-1-forwardeuler)

Comment: You know that there are no `2` values or `5` values in your `train_y` (from the shown value counts). So when you call `np.unique` you get the result `[0, 1, 3, 4, 6]` (Only 5 values). This is why when you later try to build `samples_weight` from `weight` and `train_y` you get an index out of bounds at index `6`. You might try building `class_sample_count` with `for t in range(6)` if you know the range of values or `for t in range(min(train_y), max(train_y))` depending on what behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a [mre] and explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `np.unique(train_y)` you make a list of 5 elements (6834, 1200, 4397, 1112, 3281) because the second and the fifth elements are both equal to 0. At the same time, the `train_y` still contains 7 elements.

Then you iterate through `train_y`, containing 7 elements, and on index 6 you justly receive an exception, because `weight` contains 5 elements.